# I am stuck at debugging a python 2.7.9 code for a rock paper scissors game

Tags: python, python-2.7, debugging

I am trying to make a rock-paper-scissors game in function form but it is not working properly. I tried to write it simple and it worked and i am not sure why it's not working right now. Also i like to make it a looped game where it asks the user to pick either rock, paper or scissors untill the user quits the game or presses ctrl-z. I am open to all recommendations and criticism.

```
import sys
import stdio
import random

def rps(user,computer):    
    if user == "rock":
        if computer=="Rock":
            return ("Tie!")
        elif computer=="Paper":
            return ("I win!")
        elif computer=="Scissors":
            return ("You win!")
    elif user == "paper":
        if computer=="Paper":
            return ("Tie!")
        elif computer=="Scissors":
            return ("I win!")
        elif computer=="Rock":
            return ("You win!")
    elif user == "scissors":
        if computer=="Scissors":
            return ("Tie!")
        elif computer=="Rock":
            return ("I win!")
        elif computer=="Paper":
            return ("You win!")
    else:
        return ("That is not a valid choice.Do not use uppercase letters, numbers or symbols in your choice.")

def main():
    n=["Rock","Paper","Scissors"]
    computer = random.choice(n)
    user= input ("'rock', 'paper' or 'scissors?'")
    print (computer)

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working?

Comment: There is no module `stdio`. That is C++ I think.

Comment: When i execute it, it asks me the input line "'rock', 'paper' or 'scissors?'" but when i write an aswer it only prints my answer and the computers choice. It is not checking the rps and gives me the result. And ignore the inports, i write them as a habit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you run your python script? You should get some debug output from that. When I run it, I get:

```
File "C:/Python34/test.py", line 2, in <module>
  import stdio
```

telling me that the import stdio is wrong.

In fact you do not need to import stdio (I guess you want it for print).

Now, when to program is started your main is called. At present it does not call rps, so you do net see the result of it.
But adding

```
print (rps(user,computer))
```

to your main, gets me the desired result.

```
'rock', 'paper' or 'scissors?'rock
Paper
I win!
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It really worked. I always import what i use most in case i change something, that is why i wrote it. Now for the last thing i need to make it non stop, it should ask for user to pick rock,paper or scissors untill user closes cmd or exits it by ctrl-z